# React JS element width same as its height

Tags: html, jquery, css, reactjs

I am new to React JS. Now struggled with a little thing that I need to set an element width equal to its height. We can manage with in jQuery something like below:

```js
var divWidth = $('.main').width(); 
$('.main').height(divWidth);

$( window ).resize(function() {
var divWidth = $('.main').width(); 
$('.main').height(divWidth);
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
}

.main {
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <diV class="main">
    test
  </diV>
</div>
```

**How can we do like this in React JS?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jquery window listener to pass props to a component and set it style. It will have the same effect.

```
import React, { Fragment, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function LiveVisitors() {
  const [dimensions, setDimensions] = useState({
    x: document.body.clientWidth,
    y: document.body.clientHeight
  });

  window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
    setDimensions({
      x: document.body.clientWidth,
      y: document.body.clientHeight
    });
  });

  let fraction = dimensions.x / 10;

  return (
    <div
      style={{
    border: "1px solid red",
    width: fraction,
    height: fraction
      }}
    >
      {JSON.stringify(dimensions)}
    </div>
  );
}

const wrapper = document.getElementById("container");
ReactDOM.render(<LiveVisitors />, wrapper);
```

You can modify this playground: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-v66j1?file=/index.js:0-719